# How to do data dimensionailty reduction?

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, dimension-reduction

I have a set of 25 images of label 'Infected' and 25 images of label 'Normal'. 
I am trying to extract the dual-tree complex wavelet transform based coefficients as features for each of the images.

My code to obtain coefficients using DT-CWT ia as follows:

```
I = imread('infected_img1.jpg'); %read image
I = rgb2gray(I); %rgb ro gray-scale
L = 6; %no. of levels for wavelet decomposition
I = reshape(I',1,size(I,1)*size(I,2)); %change into a vector
I = [I,zeros(1,2^L - rem(length(I),2^L))]; %pad zeros to make dim(I) a multiple of 2^L
I = double(I);
dt = dddtree('cplxdt',I,L,'dtf3'); %perform DT-CWT
dt_Coeffs = (dt.cfs{L}(:,:,1) + 1i*dt.cfs{L}(:,:,2)); %extract coefficents at Level 6
```

Now, since I have 24 more images to extract coefficients from, I do this block for each of the images. My ultimate aim is to append all coefficient vectors generated in each iteration to form a matrix. But each image tends to give a different sized coefficient vector.

I want to know about some dimension reduction method that can reduce each vector to a uniform size and at the same time preserve its information.
Can anyone suggest methods with a good amount of clarity?

Comment: Why don't you zero pad to the longest vector length instead? You can't shrink something (i.e. remove information) and still preserve all of the information.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment,

> You **can't** shrink something (i.e. **remove information**) and still **preserve all** of the **information**.

Instead you can pad all of the vectors to the length of the largest vector and then concatenate them to create a matrix. You could program your own method but in the spirit of [not reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) I've previously used [`padcat()`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22909-padcat). It is very easy to use and pads with `NaN` but you can easily change this to `0`.

Here's an example usage which also contains a handy conversion from `NaN` to `0`.

```
>> a = [1 2 3 4];
>> b = [1 2 3];
>> c = padcat(a, b);
c =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3   NaN
>> c(isnan(c)) = 0
c =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     0
```

Comment: thanks for the input @IKavanagh. What about methods like Kernel-PCA, PCA and SVD etc? I am just asking

Comment: @vishnu I'm not familiar with Kernel-PCA or PCA and no you can't use SVD.